# Why to show pop up when user close the tab in chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could you please tell me Why pop up screen or alert is not display when user close the tab in chrome ?
Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/Whospoc9SLVe6gjbsVWc?p=preview

Run code on tab by this link
http://run.plnkr.co/Tj9w5LalKQmE9w1w/

```
$scope.$on('onUnload', function (e) {
            alert('onBeforeUnlccoad')

        console.log('leaving page');
    });

    $scope.$on('onBeforeUnload', function (e) {
        alert('onBeforeUnload')
        console.log('leaving page');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think onbeforeunload specification changed silently in recent time. lets leave angular on the side and check basic example which should work.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  alert('test');
  console.log('test')
  e.returnValue = 'test';
  return 'test';
};
```

This simple piece of code handling onbeforeunload event.
How it behaves in newest chrome for example.

- it show browser default message for leaving site with confirmation box with buttons leave and cancel
- console.log is executed
- alerts, prompts and other stuff that is blocking javascript execution is automatically blocked.
- also i have observed, if we open a page with above code and will not do any interaction with page closing tab will be possible without any message, situation change when we do anything like click in the blank spot, in such case default confirmation box will appear and console log will be displayed

Its even possible to have ajax request send here for example:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  alert('test');
  console.log('test');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'send-ajax-data.php');
  xhr.send(null);

  e.returnValue = 'test';
  return 'test';
};
```

Default browser prompt is displayed and in the background ajax request is send. So some asynchronous actions can be done if they will finish before user will confirm leaving the site.

So in summary i think something you want to achieve is not possible. because there is default browser prompt it cannot be replaced with custom modal. Alers also cannot be executed.